# Use bunny fetch for loading multiple messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, eventmachine, bunny

I'm building a Ruby worker for RabbitMQ which will process multiple messages per time and will work on multiple queues.
In RabbitMQ I have: Queue1, Queue2, Queue3...

I need to quickly load big pack of packets(with basic_get I can load 65535 messages without ask). Code below worked pretty well, until we moved to a new server. Latency between queue and worker go up, and I can load only 50 messages per seconds with basic get.

This is my workflow with get:

```
def work_iteration
  cache = queue_manager.messages
  size = cache.size
  return if size == 0
  delivery_tag = process(cache)
  queue_manager.ack(delivery_tag)
  size
end
```

and in QueueManager.rb I have

```
def messages
  MULTIPLE_MESSAGES.times.reduce([]) do |s, _|
    result = basic_get
    break s if result.nil? || result.last.nil?
    s << result
  end
end

def ack(delivery_tag)
  channel.ack(delivery_tag, true)
end
```

Another workaround I've found is to use subscribe method. But I haven't found way to break subscribe from inner loop.

```
queue_manager.subscribe do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  cache << [delivery_info, properties, payload]
  if cache.size >= 65_000
    dt = process(cache)
    queue_manager.ack(dt)
  end
end
```

I googled and found that this can work for me:

```
length = queue.size
cache = [] 
consumer = queue.subscribe(block: false) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  cache << [delivery_info, properties, payload]
  if cache.size >= length
    dt = process(cache)
    queue.ack(dt)
    consumer.cancel
  end
end
```

- But what happens in main thread then?
- How to properly block main thread, and unblock when processing is finished?
- Is there is other way to load multiple messages from queue, process them, close consumer and move to next queue?